# Need a multi-line textbox control with both horizontal and vertical scrolling and optional word wrap for MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to have an on-screen scrollable log window for an Access application. Limitations of built-in textbox types include no way to turn off word wrap and no support for horizontal scrolling. An MS Forms 2.0 ActiveX control looked promising but I found that resizing the text box to accommodate more lines is not handled the way I need - it altered the font size instead; plus, the font and size is not selectable and I want to support flexible fonts. There's an Outlook ActiveX text box control in my list but selecting it causes an error about registration. There's an MS Rich Text ActiveX control in the list but Access says it's "unsupported" (no more info provided).

Any suggestions? Extensive web searching has yielded only dead ends.

Thx
Tom